# Asp.Net Core: Use memory cache outside controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, memorycache

In ASP.NET Core its very easy to access your memory cache from a controller

In your startup you add:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
             services.AddMemoryCache();
        }
```

and then from your controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyExampleController : Controller
{
    private IMemoryCache _cache;

    public MyExampleController(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _cache = memoryCache;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "DoStuff")]
    public string Get(string id)
    {
        var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
        _cache.Set("key", "value", cacheEntryOptions);
    }
}
```

But, how can I access that same memory cache outside of the controller. eg. I have a scheduled task that gets initiated by HangFire, How do I access the memorycache from within my code that starts via the HangFire scheduled task?

```
public class ScheduledStuff
{
    public void RunScheduledTasks()
    {
        //want to access the same memorycache here ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Memory cache instance may be injected to the any component that is controlled by DI container; this means that you need configure `ScheduledStuff` instance in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  services.AddMemoryCache();
  services.AddSingleton<ScheduledStuff>();
}
```

and declare IMemoryCache as dependency in ScheduledStuff constructor:

```
public class ScheduledStuff {
  IMemoryCache MemCache;
  public ScheduledStuff(IMemoryCache memCache) {
    MemCache = memCache;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Vitaliy. The problem now is, how can I kick off the RunScheduledTasks method? It requires the memoryCache parameter. Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'memoryCache' of 'ScheduledStuff.ScheduledStuff(IMemoryCache)'

    `ScheduledStuff scheduledStuff = new ScheduledStuff();` <- Error here
    `scheduledStuff.RunScheduledTasks();`

Comment: you shouldn't create `SheduledStuff` instance in your code, instead of this you need to get it from DI container - by defining it as dependency in Controller, or with `HttpContext.RequestServices`.

Answer (score 8):

I am bit late here, but just wanted to add a point to save someone's time. You can access IMemoryCache through HttpContext anywhere in application

```
var cache = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMemoryCache>();
```

Please make sure to add MemeoryCache in Startup

```
services.AddMemoryCache();
```

Comment: Getting error when using HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMemoryCache>(); : An object reference is required for the non static field, method or property.

Comment: HttpContext isnt available _everywhere_.  This will only work in a controller, or something with a context.

Comment: misleading response. It is not accessible 'anywhere' throughout the 'application'.

Answer (score 4):

There is another very flexible and easy way to do it is using `System.Runtime.Caching/MemoryCache`

**System.Runtime.Caching/MemoryCache:**
This is pretty much the same as the old day's ASP.Net MVC's `HttpRuntime.Cache`. **You can use it on ASP.Net CORE without any dependency injection**, in any class you want to. This is how to use it:

```
// First install 'System.Runtime.Caching' (NuGet package)

// Add a using
using System.Runtime.Caching;

// To get a value
var myString = MemoryCache.Default["itemCacheKey"];

// To store a value
MemoryCache.Default["itemCacheKey"] = myString;
```